# How to start all chapters with an odd-numbered page

Tags: thesis

How to start all chapters with an odd-numbered page? including:
Contents, List of Figures, List of Tables, Nomenclature, Abstract, Acknowledgments, All Chapters, Appendixes, and References

The code of `.cls` file in this link https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/101GvLp6hknlY0TTdSl3r8ZkmH8IUm7de?usp=sharing

The following code is from the main `.tex`  file

```
\documentclass{yakout}
%\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
%\hyphenpenalty=1000
%\hbadness=1000

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\MTCmaketitle 
\MTCmarginsR
\MTCPre
\MTCmarginsA
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\include{chapter1}    
\include{chapter2}  
\include{chapter3}   
\include{chapter4}   
\include{chapter5}    
\include{chapter6}   
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\MTCref
\MTCAppendix
\MTCarabic

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code is not compilable. Please make it compilable without the need of installing extra files. For now, just: choose the option \twoside for your document class and have a look whether \input{chapter} instead of \include{chapter} answers some of your questions. In general \cleardoublepage helps a lot where \twoside does not do it automatically.

Comment: There is also the `openright` option, which is not the default in some classes.